# apache2 rewrite page not found

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Ive just completed the setup of apache.

Setup looks as follow:

my virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName system.local
    ServerAlias www.system.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/system
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My hosts file is:

```
   127.0.1.1       system.local
```

I have also used a2enmod to enable mod_rewrite.

When i open my application and for instance go to /Admins/index i get a page not found.

Does anyone know what i might be missing?

Comment: Are you using and htacess file?

Comment: @PanamaJack Yes i am but i am 100% sure that these work since they worked on my older linux mint computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an .htaccess file. You need to allow the use of an .htaccess file in your web directory using `AllowOverride All`. For that your code should look like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName learningbank.local
    ServerAlias www.learningbank.local
    DocumentRoot /var/www/system_learningbank
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/system_learningbank>
     AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also don't forget to restart apache when making config changes.